# What means "HD" in the source code for java classes Integer and Long?

Tags: java, comments, bit-manipulation

Inside the source code of Integer.java and Long.java, in most of the bit twiddling methods, there is a commented reference to something called "HD". Each method points to a particular section of said reference.

What is that reference?

Here is an example in method `highestOneBit(int)` from class `Integer` (source code [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Integer.java.html), line 1035):

```
/**
 * Returns an {@code int} value with at most a single one-bit, in the
 * position of the highest-order ("leftmost") one-bit in the specified
 * {@code int} value.  Returns zero if the specified value has no
 * one-bits in its two's complement binary representation, that is, if it
 * is equal to zero.
 *
 * @return an {@code int} value with a single one-bit, in the position
 *     of the highest-order one-bit in the specified value, or zero if
 *     the specified value is itself equal to zero.
 * @since 1.5
 */
public static int highestOneBit(int i) {
    // HD, Figure 3-1
    i |= (i >>  1);
    i |= (i >>  2);
    i |= (i >>  4);
    i |= (i >>  8);
    i |= (i >> 16);
    return i - (i >>> 1);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the comments at the top of the source code...

```
   40    * <p>Implementation note: The implementations of the "bit twiddling"
   41    * methods (such as {@link #highestOneBit(int) highestOneBit} and
   42    * {@link #numberOfTrailingZeros(int) numberOfTrailingZeros}) are
   43    * based on material from Henry S. Warren, Jr.'s <i>Hacker's
   44    * Delight</i>, (Addison Wesley, 2002).
   45    *
```

[Hacker's Delight](http://www.informit.com/store/hackers-delight-9780201914658) by Henry S. Warren.